# How to track the down arrow button in virtual keyboard?

Tags: android, softkeys

[image]

> In the above figure i want to listen for down arrow( i have marked it in red colour, the key one which is used to hide the keyboard). I have tried to get it action through menu options, viewconfiguration class etc. But it is not useful. Is there any method, listeners or any callback event to track this button. Please let me know your suggestions and thoughts. Any help in this regard is highly appreciable

Thanks inAdvance

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: plz answer if you have figure out!

Comment: No, Still I have no clue about this. AFAIK different manufactures use different key codes in return for this particular event.

Answer (score -1):

In your activity, override this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()

Comment: Have you tried it ever?? It dosen't work for me. It will not work. Actually it is not back button. Please do a revisit my button. Many will have confusions. That's why i have added the figure. I want the action for the button,(which i have marked in red). the above marked button will not trigger back button. If you click on this button it will hide keyboard and then the back button came in the position of this button and then you click on it and if you have overriden onBackpresed() method, you will get call back on it. Please do a check on it

Comment: Hi All,  I have found that many of them are confused with the way i asked the question. Now I have Updated the question. Please go through the updated question

Answer (score -2):

If I am not you talking about this method

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    switch(keyCode)
    {

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
     Toast.makeText(KeyActions.this, "Pressed Back Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```