# how to hide the footer fragment when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have footer bar in my activity. I used fragment for footer bar. here is screen shot. [image: screen_1]. When I add the text into the `EditText`, the keyboard show like this. [image: screen_2]. I would like to hide the footer when the keyboard appear. I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in activity. I would like to know any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `onTouchListener` to the `EditText` and when touched, hide the footer programmatically (`setVisibility = "GONE"`). If you can't manage to do it, let me know and paste the XML of this layout.

Comment: Yes. it's ok using `onTouchListener`. But when the keyboard hide, the footer should be shown again.

Comment: The keyboard hides on which event? I would guess when the Enter key is pressed - right (or the arrow down)? You can detect those easily, try it in google I immediatley found tons of examples for detecting those events.

Comment: Could u please give me example of usage? I found this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16159802/1156041 question but no suitable answer.

Comment: Ok, I didn't find anything regarding this button in particular, but here's what you can do: `public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //Log the keyCode and the KeyEvent here, return with the results
    return true;
}` After the log you did, please return with the results of it and will post a complete answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The result is nothing. I haven't got key code when I touch arrow down. I have no idea why? When I touch other key, I got key code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33764/discussion-between-user1156041-and-g00dy)

Comment: I found suitable solution for me here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8827112/1156041. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i have faced same situation, and dont have finded any solution,so just started another activity on touch of textview. on completion of activity again in this activity gotted result back from the textview of next activity and placed the text in current activity's textview. it works

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem i just removed android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   from my manifest file and i got the desired output

Answer (score -1):

```
var originalHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var originalWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Control landscape/portrait mode switch
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight == originalWidth &&
         document.documentElement.clientWidth == originalHeight) {
        originalHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        originalWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }`enter code here`
    // Check if the available height is smaller (keyboard is shown) so we hide the footer.
   if (document.documentElement.clientHeight < originalHeight) {
       $('.footer').hide();
   } else {
       $('.footer').show();
   }
});

try this it will work and  give  class="footer"
```

Comment: is android, not javascript

Comment: @Frank  I provided the solution for Cordova / PhoneGap,  Thanks for the info.