# What's the name of the "arrow-down" button?

Tags: java, android

I want to override a method like the "onBackPressed()"-method but I don't know how the keycode is called of the button I'm looking for.
Does anyone know how this button is called?
I know this question was already asked in a similiar way and if you want to see a picture of what I mean klcik here:

[How to track the down arrow button in virtual keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159802/how-to-track-the-down-arrow-button-in-virtual-keyboard)

And no, the button can't be addressed with onBackPressed()!!!!

Thanks! :)

Comment: I do not think that there is any way to track or prevent the input method editor from being closed via the BACK button. Despite the icon change, that is still the BACK button.

Comment: But I does not work. If I choose another button like 'A' or 'B' it works. So it can't be the BACK-button...

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "another button like 'A' or 'B'". If you mean that you are implementing the input method editor, I would not expect you to find out when that button gets clicked, though I would expect that there is some way for you to know that the input method editor has been closed by the user.

Comment: I mean that I just need the name of this buton because I can set an onClickListener on it and perfrom the action I want.
With every other button on the keyboard it works

Comment: It is not a button on which you can set a listener.

Comment: And how can I add special behaviour for this button if I can't set an Listener?

Comment: Quoting my original comment: "I do not think that there is any way to track or prevent the input method editor from being closed via the BACK button. Despite the icon change, that is still the BACK button."